# How to prove that : $\int_{2}^{x}\frac{dO(te^{-c\sqrt{\log t}})}{t\log t}=O(1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$\displaystyle{
\mbox{How I can prove that}\
\int_{2}^{x}{\,\mathrm{d}\alpha\left(t\right) \over t\,\log\left(t\right)} =
\,\mathrm{O}\left(1\right)\ ?,}\quad
$
where
$\alpha\left(t\right) =
\,\mathrm{O}\left(te^{-c\,\sqrt{\,\log\left(t\right)\,\,}\,}\right)$  and $c>0$.

Comment: What do you mean with $$dO(te^{-c\sqrt{\log t}})$$ ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM; this is the Riemann–Stieltjes integral

Comment: It's the $O$ in the integrand that's weird. Please explain.

Comment: @zhw. I changed my writing I hope it will be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I will use the symbol $\ll
 $ instead of $O\left(*\right)
 $. Using integration by parts, we have $$\int_{2}^{x}\frac{d\alpha\left(t\right)}{t\log\left(t\right)}dt=\frac{\alpha\left(2\right)}{2\log\left(2\right)}-\frac{\alpha\left(x\right)}{x\log\left(x\right)}-\int_{2}^{x}\alpha\left(t\right)d\left(\frac{1}{t\log\left(t\right)}\right)
 $$ and now, since $\frac{1}{t\log\left(t\right)}
 $ is a $C^{1}
 $ function, we have $$-\int_{2}^{x}\alpha\left(t\right)d\left(\frac{1}{t\log\left(t\right)}\right)=\int_{2}^{x}\frac{\alpha\left(t\right)\left(\log\left(t\right)+1\right)}{t^{2}\log^{2}\left(t\right)}dt.
 $$ Now since $\alpha\left(t\right)\ll te^{-c\sqrt{\log\left(t\right)}}\ll\frac{t}{\log\left(t\right)}
 $ we have $$\ll\int_{2}^{x}\frac{e^{-c\sqrt{\log\left(x\right)}}}{t\log\left(t\right)}dt\ll\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{t\log^{2}\left(t\right)}dt=-\frac{1}{\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{\log\left(2\right)}\ll1
 $$ since $x\geq2$.